# TCP Provider Issue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2014

Error :

> TCP Provider: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.**

Things I have worked out so far :

1. I enabled REMOTE CONNECTIONS on both servers A (SQL Server 2008 R2) and B (SQL Server 2014).Both default SQL Servers(MSSQLSERVER).
2. I turned on both servers and enabled SQL Port 1433 and SQL Browser port UDP 1434.
3. TCP/IP enabled on both servers.
4. I started SQL Browser service on both servers.

But still I am facing above issue. Please help me solve it.

Comment: Did you restart sql server services after you enabled TCP/IP ?

Comment: Kin as the TCP IP/IP is already enabled,I did not restart the service.

Comment: Kin is there any issue because my SQL Servers: one is sql server 2008 R2 and other is SQL Server 2014 and have AOAGs enabled on database ?